# memory management problems in xcode 4

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode4

As the title states, is anyone else facing memory management problems when using Xcode 4? my projects run perfectly when running with Xcode 3 but shows many warnings and crashes due to memory mismanagement... 
I would also like to know if the latest Xcode update added more memory management rules...

Comment: Check to see if you are using LLVM instead of GCC... Qiau is right though; the IDE itself can't cause memory issues with your app.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so should I be using GCC instead of LLVM?

Comment: Either should work; and I'm not clear on the advantages of one over the other (other than LLVM is newer; the direction Apple is headed). But with the switch to xcode 4, it's possible you switched from GCC to LLVM, which could theoretically expose a memory management issue that you weren't seeing before.

Comment: I'd definitely investigate the actual issue and cause of the crash though. If there's an error that only shows up in LLVM, it's still a bug in your code that should be fixed.

Comment: I agree with you on that... thanks for the reply...

Comment: @Gendolkari where can I find out whether I am using GCC or LLVM??

Comment: Click the project name in your navigator; this will open up the project settings window. In there, look for "Compiler Version."

Comment: @Gendolkari I just checked it... Under compiler version it says C/C++ Compiler Version  GCC 4.2... that means I am using the GCC compiler right? The thing I dont understand is how it is working perfectly in xcode 3 and crashing in xcode 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory management problems is IDE independent, so the answer is "No".
If you have problems in xcode3, they will be there if you edit your code in xcode4 or notepad too.

Maybe the real problem is something else?

Comment: thanks for the reply. well the thing is that the project works perfectly on xcode 3 without throwing any errors or warnings... but when I run it in xcode 4, it crashes and also throws memory exceptions...